# Changing Title Color in Zephyr Theme on Joomla

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

Joomla! 1.5 Version of the Zephyr Template Question

I've searched at length but haven't found a direct parallel to my issue but I'm hoping it's a simple one.

All of the titles on the site are set to #000000

I would like to change all of them to #c3c665

I've tried changing the template.css lines that read:
/* Modules */
.module-title .title {margin-top: 0;font-weight: normal;font-size: 130%;padding: 0;letter-spacing: 1px;}

To be:
/* Modules */
.module-title .title {margin-top: 0;font-weight: normal;font-size: 130%;padding: 0;letter-spacing: 1px; color:#c3c665;}

But nothing happens?

I've tried using Firebug as well to track it down, but haven't had much luck and I'm hoping someone more versed w/ firebug, or who knows Joomla a bit better could tell me where I'm going wrong.

Link to site: http://www.transformaison.com/index.php

The text I'd like to change the color of is ALL titles, most notably on the home page:

"Lorem Ipsum" - Mainbody article title

All module titles, such as "Contact Information" and "Professional Designations"

Where is this color set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, line 45 if index.php has class `.title` being #000000, which is overriding the template.  Disabling that, and using your preferred color worked fine for me.

Specifically in index.php which is keeping #000000, removing the `.title` should probably do it.

```
.box8, .box8 .title, .box8 a:hover, .box11, .box11 .title, .box11 a:hover, .title3 .module-title .title {color:#000000 !important;}
```